# V-tail induced roll and main wing design considerations

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, v-tail

If the only difference between two hypothetical aircrafts is that one has a conventional V-tail, while the other has an inverted V-tail, then, when rudder pedal is pressed a conventional V-tail induces an adverse roll, while the inverted V-tail induces a proverse roll due to the V-tail also acting a bit as ailerons.

How does this impact main wing design?  Would the wing's ailerons volume have to be different, or dihedral angle changed between the two aircrafts?   Or, can this be neglected depending on the rolling inertia the wings create?

I have no idea if the this is the correct term, but by "rolling inertia" I mean both rotational moment of inertia of the wing that is always the same whatever the airspeed, and some dynamic inertia due to air massflow passing by the wing, making it virtually more massive(?)

[image]

Comment: I can give you a reference - https://www.fmsg-alling.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/V-Leitwerke.pdf

Comment: The rolling moment you get depends on where you locate the base of the V relative to the vertical C of G.  Mount an inverted V high enough, and most of the rolling moment is coming from the yaw force displacement from vertical, which is opposite to and cancels out much of the rolling moment induced by the individual surfaces when operated as rudder input.